# itext7 -- System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, itext, itext7

I tried POC in itext PDF generator for Xamarin forms apps(Android & IOS),

Scenarios Checked:
**itext sharp Version:5.5.21** - Both in PCL projects and Native Projects worked fine. 
**itext7 Version:7.1.0** - got below error

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'iText.IO.Util.ResourceUtil' threw an exception. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.DependencyContextLoader' threw an 
exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.DependencyContextPaths' threw an 
exception. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not 
implemented.
```

In forums it's been said this have fixed in previous version. Any thing i need to initialize before.Attach Below tried code,

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(fs, new WriterProperties().AddXmpMetadata()));
Document document = new Document(pdf);

pdf.SetTagged();
pdf.GetCatalog().SetLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
pdf.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));
PdfDocumentInfo info = pdf.GetDocumentInfo();
info.SetTitle("iText7 PDF/UA example");

PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FONT, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.SetFont(font);
 p.Add(new Text("The quick brown "));

document.Add(p);
document.Close();
```

While breakpoint hits PdfFont it raises above error.

Answer (score 1):

You have code that works for iText 5, but not for iText 7. That is normal. iText 7 is a complete rewrite (from scratch!) of iText 5. The API is not backward compatible, so if you have iText 5 code, you have to rewrite it (from scratch!) if you want that code to work for iText 7.

You get all those exceptions because all of those methods (and even many of those classes) no longer exist in iText 7; they have been replaced with other methods (and classes).

This tutorial will give you a jump-start: [iText 7: Jump-start tutorial for .NET](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version)

Comment: I have installed itext7 from nuget. Same code works fine ,when executed as console application but it didn't work in Xamarin forms and PCL.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same trouble with itext7 (2023) for an WPF app but maybe it can help here too, i cleared my build repository then rebuild my code and it works fine. So i can suggest you to try the same, clear your /bin/debug or /release depend on the one you use and give it a try.